# updating ProgressBar in android

Tags: android, progress-bar, touch-event, ontouchlistener

```
Image.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Trace(array);
                .....
                int  print_prog;
                int total_pixels = mPixels_printedpixelcomparison.capacity();
                **print_prog** = (printedpixel/total_pixels)*100;
                printProgress.setProgress(**print_prog**);
                ......
           }




  private Bitmap Trace(int[] imageArray)
  {
    .....
    printedpixel +=100;
    .....   


 }
```

> in the above code **print_prog** is always a zero and there is no changes in my progress bar either(its just blank) cause of the zero...can anyone help me out with this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is `int` division.  In Java, `int` division truncates remainders, so that it can return an `int`.

```
(printedpixel/total_pixels)*100;
```

`printedpixel/total_pixels` will always return 0 because of this.  And 0*100 is always going to be 0.

You can fix this by using `double`'s or `float`'s.

```
double  print_prog;
double total_pixels = (double) mPixels_printedpixelcomparison.capacity();
**print_prog** = (printedpixel/total_pixels)*100;
printProgress.setProgress(**print_prog**);
```

Comment: setProgress() API accepts only int....and int, it does truncates, but still it should have the value right??? why it is zero???

Comment: @jxgn it truncates because, for instance, 150/200 = 0.75. Then `75` part is truncated because it is Int and you always have 0.

Comment: so what about the 100 i multiply??

Comment: ok changed to float and typecasted the print_prog to int inside setProgress(), that works.....thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @nicholas.hauschild is correct, however the simpler and faster solution will be to replace

```
(printedpixel/total_pixels)*100;
```

with

```
(printedpixel*100/total_pixels);
```

Comment: @jxgn if `printedpixel` and `total_pixels` are `Int`s, then `(printedpixel*100/total_pixels)` also would be an `Int`